# Do contactless payments work on Android 4x these days?

Tags: nfc, google-pay, samsung-pay

I've seen info that current version of Google Pay requires Android 5 or higher. Is it possible to install and use any application like Google Pay on Android 4.x (with NFC)?

Comment: Your question already contains the answer: Google Pay requires Android 5. And as Android 4.4. is below 5% and even more important it is a security nightmare because of all these unmitigated security vulnerabilities found in the past years no vendor with good judgement would support a payment solution for such an old platform.

Comment: @Robert thanks.

Comment: @Robert though my question doesn't contain the answer, I ask if something like possible to use, not necessarily Google's application.

Comment: For NFC payment the common way would be to use the "Host-based card emulation" mode which has been introduced in Android 4.4. Therefore this version would be the only one where it would be theoretically possible but as I wrote security of this version is a nightmare and the number of Android 4.4 devices that have an NFC reader should be very low.